# Mathematical inspiration from my bathroom floor

Tags: soft-question

I spend some time each day contemplating the grid pattern of my bathroom vinyl floor covering:[image]

What neat, not too difficult mathematical concepts are embodied in such a pattern? I've thought of a couple. First, the proof that rational numbers are countable:[image]

Second, showing that$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}=1$$[image]

I would love to hear of  others.

Comment: So, you are basically asking for a list of results that can be visualized on a grid. According to some, this could be unnecessarily broad or lengthy to accomplish. Notice, however, that the second one you mentioned is not visualized correctly.

Comment: I was hoping you would say something about the different shades of the tiles. Maybe theres something interesting there

Answer (score 7):

**1. Sums over the grid.** 
The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is actually $n^2$:

> $$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-3)+(2n-1)=\sum^n_{k=1} (2k-1) = n^2.$$

[image: No, I don't wanna enter an image description, thanks.] Moreover, you can express any odd number as a difference of squares: $$2n-1=n^2-(n-1)^2.$$ Or any sum of consecutive odd numbers for that matter: $$\sum^n_{k=m} (2k-1) = \left(\sum^n_{k=1} -\sum^{m-1}_{k=1}\right) (2k-1) = n^2 -(m-1)^2.$$

Or even better: the sum of the first $n$ cubes equals the squared sum of the first $n$ integers:

> $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots+(n-1)^3+n^3 =\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 =\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2 =\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

This can also be seen on a grid:
[image: Sum of cubes equals the squared sum of naturals]
from: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Nicomachus_theorem_3D.svg

Here's more. If you have a sum over a square grid (as in assigning each tile a number), you can compute the same sum over just (a triangular) half of the whole region (plus the diagonal strip):

> Let $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. Let $f:S\times S\to$ any field. Then
>   $$\sum_{x=1}^n \ \sum_{y=1}^n f(x,y) = \sum_{x=1}^n \left(f(x,x) +\sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \big(f(x,y)+f(y,x)\big)\right)$$ when the sums are finite.

This is easier to see with integrals: let $g:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to[a,b]\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$, then $$\int^1_0\int^1_0 g(x,y)\ \text{d}y\ \text{d}x=\int^1_0\int^x_0\big(g(x,y)+g(y,x)\big)\ \text{d}y\ \text{d}x.$$

If you place an origin at the centre of your grid, you can also divide the grid in four square smaller grids, or eight triangular grids.

[image: Grid splitted in halves, quarters and eighths]

**2. Spirals on the grid.**
You can also draw square spirals on the grid, such as [Ulam's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral%20Ulam's).

**3. Golden rectangles.**
Consider drawing squares on the grid following this pattern (starting at the upper $1$ tile):

[image: Greek rectangles and the Golden Ratio]

Applications aside, the numbers $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots$ are the Fibonacci sequence. Look at the outer rectangle: the more squares you add to it, the closer the ratio of its side lengths gets to the golden ratio $1.618$.

**4. Computer screens.**
The screen you are reading right now is just a huge grid of tiny little dot lights. Computers can't represent continuous stuff, so they approximate continuous with small straight lines made up of square points (pixels). Hopefully, it gives the optical ilusion of continuous smooth curves when seen from afar. This is mathematically relevant as of the use of graphicators.

**5. Games/problems that rely heavily on grids:**
Chess, checkers, sudokus, magic squares, ["squaring the square" (tiling an integral square using only other integral squares)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoRjwZomUK0), crosswords, pixel art, nonograms, Battleship, Dungeons and Dragons, most $2$D Super Mario Bros. videogames, tic-tac-toe, Connect $4$, lines and dots, Tetris, among others.

Comment: I'll never look at my bathroom floor in the same way again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your basic

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

[image]

Comment: Basic? I would never have seen that in a month of Sundays.

Comment: @Peter4075 Oh, I thought that one was pretty well known! I've got a few others but it'll take me some time to create the graphics .... check back a in a few days!

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the problem of how many paths there are from one corner of a rectangle to another:

[image]

Also, you can visualize Pascal's triangle and some of the patterns within it.
For example, here I get the Fibonacci numbers out of it (I will leave it as an exercise to see why this pattern continues):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can think about the Euler characteristic of a planar region. Draw diagonals for each small square to get a triangulation of the floor. Then check if the Euler characteristic (the alternating sum of vertices, edges and faces) is in fact 1, which it should be since it is homotopic to a point -- unless your tailing is not simply connected!

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2, not 1?

Answer (score 1):

**Pick's Theorem**

Given a simple polygon constructed on a grid of equal-distanced points (i.e., points with integer coordinates) such that all the polygon's vertices are grid points, Pick's theorem provides a simple formula for calculating the area $A$ of this polygon in terms of the number i of lattice points in the interior located in the polygon and the number $b$ of lattice points on the boundary placed on the polygon's perimeter:

$$A = i + \frac{b}{2} - 1$$

Comment: As a maths novice, all these answers have all been instructive. What stands out for me so far are Pick's Theorem and the Euler characteristic, neither of which I have come across before. There's a very nice Pick's Theorem proof that makes use of the Euler characteristic on YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYW1zOMCQno